# What does "autolyco-sentimental" mean?

Tags: meaning, prefixes, music

Wagner is said to have described Mayerbeer's operas as follows:

(translated into English and originally written in German, probably.)

"Meyerbeer ... wanted a monstrous, piebald, historico-romantic, diabolico-religious, fanatica-libidinous, sacra-frivolous, mysterio-criminal, ***autolyco***-sentimental dramatic hodgepodge ..."

I can never even guess what "autolyco-" means. I didn't find any definition in any dictionary in any language. But this is quoted in a few books.

What is the answer?

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: I saw this on The Lives of the Great Composers by Harold C. Scheonberg, Chapter 16.

Comment: @PeterMortenson "I found no definition..." is perfectly grammatical, as is "Does anyone know what X means?" As the saying goes,  *there is more than one way to skin a cat*.

Comment: From the actual etymology that @Mick found and the original German (quite different from the English translation) that Insipid Snoot found, it is not too far off to determine that everybody here is just making up stuff, Wagner, the translator, even Berlioz (Meyerbeer on the other hand...). A bit gaunerisch if you will if not exactly sacro-frivolous.

Comment: Perhaps this was meant to be **analytico-sentimental**, in keeping with the other pairs. It’s an *oddico-normality* brought on by excessive machine use.

Comment: @Mitch Hey! The question originally asked "What does **autyloco**-sentimental mean?" If you want made-up stuff, just say the word.

Comment: @GlobalCharm That was my first impression, but the pairs aren't necessarily opposites, just incongruities. And 'Autolycos', despite the (to me obscure) Greek 
 mythology reference, works as a translation (Autolycos was a thief, and that is one of the meanings of 'gauner').

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The quote is not Berlioz but from [Wagner’s book-length essay “Oper und Drama” (Opera and Drama)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_and_Drama). Wagner wrote it in 1851, and it was published the following year in Leipzig.

Your text is just one translation, the one that runs:

> Weber wanted a Drama that could pass with all its members, with every scenic
>   nuance, into his noble, soulful Melody: — Meyerbeer, on the contrary,
>   wanted a monstrous piebald, historico-romantic, diabolico-religious,
>   fanatico-libidinous, sacro-frivolous, mysterio-criminal,
>   **autolyco-sentimental dramatic hotch-potch**, therein to find material for a
>   curious chimeric music, — a want which, owing to the indomitable buckram
>   of his musical temperament, could never be quite suitably supplied.

But here’s another, this time from Edwin Evan’s 1913 translation, where the translator has seized on different wording here:

> Weber wanted a libretto of such character as to enable it, at all times and 
>   with every scenic shade of colouring, to rise up into his noble soulful
>   melody. Meyerbeer, on the other hand, wanted a huge, parti-coloured,
>   historico-romantic, satanico-pious, dogmatico-lewd, sancto-nonsensical,
>   mystico-daring, **sentimentally roguish, stagy conglomeration** of all sorts,
>   in order to provide him with the occasion for inventing fearfully curious
>   music which, however, could never prove successful in application, in
>   consequence of the natural thickness of his musical skin.

So this is talking about some “roguish” activity — as Mick notes, alluding to a thieving figure from classical mythology who used tricks to deceive his neighbors.

Seems pretty roguish to me.

Comment: Yes, it was Wagner who said it. My mistake. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 29):

**Autolyco-** From the Greek *autolycus*, meaning "the wolf itself" (i.e. savage, without sentiment).

[Wikipedia: Autolycus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autolycus)

So, *autolyco-sentimental* is, perhaps, an oxymoron meaning both with and without sentiment.

Also:

> **Autolycus**
>
> Greek mythology
>
> A thief who stole cattle from his neighbour Sisyphus and prevented him from recognizing them by making them invisible

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/autolycus)

Comment: _Auto-_ self, _lyco-_ wolf (as in lycanthropy, or being a werewolf - _lyco-_ wolf, and _anthropos_, man). Etymology is such fun!

Comment: @marcellothearcane The translator took the German for 'thieving/roguish/scoundrel' and chose the mythological representative name. Whether that actual name's etymology really implies in all its uses 'thieving' is up to classicists.

Comment: @Mitch yes, my comment above was a little self-discovery regarding etymology. It could just as reasonably be someone that howls at themselves at night.

Comment: So the thief named “the wolf himself” stole a bunch of sheep and “made them invisible”?

Comment: I wouldn't say oxymoronic. It is perfectly possible to be sentimental about the times before one was sentimental, for that reason alone. It seems also appropriate if you miss a time when you were more ruthless or uncaring.

Comment: @StianYttervik I wasn't terribly happy with *oxymoronic*, but I couldn't think of anything else. tchrist's *roguishly-sentimental* is definitely better.

Answer (score 12):

Completing @tchrist's answer (since I'm not able to comment), here is a quote from the original, which you can read in its entirety [here](https://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/oper-und-drama-843/9):

> Weber
>      wollte ein Drama hergestellt haben, das überall, mit jeder szenischen
>      Nuance in seine edle, seelenvolle Melodie aufzugehen vermochte –
>      Meyerbeer wollte dagegen ein ungeheuer buntscheckiges,
>      historisch-romantisches, teuflisch-religiöses, bigott-wollüstiges,
>      frivol-heiliges, geheimnisvoll-freches, **sentimental-gaunerisches**,
>      dramatisches Allerlei haben, um an ihm erst Stoff zum Auffinden einer
>      ungeheuer kuriosen Musik zu gewinnen – was ihm wegen des unbesieglichen
>      Leders seines eigentlichen musikalischen Naturelles wiederum nie
>      wirklich recht gelingen wollte.

I'm not a native speaker of either English or German, but it's obvious that both translations are way off the mark -- the original, while trite, is not so heavy, and has no made-up words. "Gauner" is very common term for a small criminal.

The translation also fails to convey the not so subtle dog-whistling (playing on the fact that Meyerbeer was a Jew).

Comment: Keep this up and you'll be able to comment in no time.

Comment: 1. Not trite. Other than _historisch-romantisch_, the hyphenated adjectives are all absurd nonce words, i.e., made up, accentuating the random, chaotic relationship of text and music Wagner imputes to Meyerbeer. 2. A series of eight adjectives with all but two hyphenated compounds is heavy in any language. This sentence is a translator's nightmare. I'm not sure where you're hearing the dog whistle, but a bit earlier in this chapter, Wagner blandly states that as a Jew, Meyerbeer had no true native language and thus no feel for a libretto. Wagner's fullblown anti-Semitism comes later.